# How do I check to see if that element already exists before I add it?

Tags: asp.net

Trying to search web.config using ConfigurationElementCollection.

Here's the article source:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules/add

Here's a snippet of c# code I'm trying to use:

```
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site/app1");
            ConfigurationSection modulesSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/modules");
            ConfigurationElementCollection modulesCollection = modulesSection.GetCollection();

            ConfigurationElement addElement = modulesCollection.CreateElement("remove");
            addElement["name"] = @"CartHeader";
            //addElement["type"] = @"Contoso.ShoppingCart.Header";
            //addElement["preCondition"] = @"managedHandler";

            // Check if your CartHeader module exists
            var exists = modulesCollection.Any(m => m.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals("CartHeader"));
            // Handle accordingly
            if (!exists)
            {
                // Create your module here
                modulesCollection.Add(addElement);
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
```

How do I check to see if that element already exists before I add it?

I changed the CreateElement("remove") and I added a check before trying to add the element but apparently it doesn't take `<remove>` elements into consideration because it keeps adding it. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to loop through the modules collection and compare the elements with what you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

You could likely use a bit of LINQ to query and see if an element with that specific name attribute exists via the [`Enumerable.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) method :

```
// Check if your CartHeader module exists
var exists = modulesCollection.Any(m => m.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals("CartHeader"));
// Handle accordingly
if(!exist)
{
     // Create your module here
}
```

Comment: apparently the search will not find <remove name="CartHeader"/>. Search works fine if it's <add name="CartHeader"/>